# Does Gon Have Feelings For Retz?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

In a few YouTube videos, there is a a girl called Retz. It's kind of obvious she has slit feelings for Gon, and so I was wondering, does Gon had feelings for Retz?

Answer (score 2):

Nop. There is no evidence to support Gon has feelings for Retz. Killua is jealous of the fact that Gon and Retz hit it off as good friends that quickly. But later its revealed Retz is infact

> Just a Puppet!

The Wikia entry for [Retz](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Retz) summarises it in the trivia

> - It is hinted that she harbors feelings towards Gon. When Omokage cynically asks her whether she is in love with Gon or not, she remains silent. 
>  - Given that she herself is a puppet, it is safe to say that instead of deceased, she simply ceased to be.

You should watch the movie to know more. [HxH : Phantom Rouge](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter:_Phantom_Rouge)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely has feelings, but not on the romantic level more so of a friend and how close can one get with a puppet.